# Jekyll - How can I make avoid a paragraph to be added on a YAML frontmatter markdownify item

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

Okay... I have a project where I'm using Jekyll for a podcast project. And I chose to list the hosts in the shownotes by a YAML Front Matter item:

```
hosts:
  - Name A
  - Name B
  - Name C
```

Using this piece of code

```
<li> <strong>Hosts:</strong>
<ul>
  {% for host in page.hosts %}
<li>{{ host }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I receive the correct list

```
<ul>
<li> <strong>Hosts:</strong> 
<ul> 
  <li>Name A </li>
  <li>Name B </li>
  <li>Name C </li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

However, I want to markdownify this by doing

```
<li> <strong>Hosts:</strong>
<ul>
  {% for host in page.hosts %}
<li>{{ host | markdownify }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But Jekyll returns:

```
<ul>
<li> <strong>Hosts:</strong> 
<ul> 
  <li><p>Name A </p></li>
  <li><p>Name B </p></li>
  <li><p>Name C </p></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Any way to forbid Jekyll to add the `<p>` tag into the list item? Actually, if I want to add any rich formatting, I need to put HTML directly into the items, but I want to add it via Markdown'ing the Front Matter text. Any suggestions?

**PS:** my site is hosted at Github Pages

Comment: I know this is old, but most markdown parsers would handle it better if you would write proper html.
`<li>{{ host }}` is missing the trailing `</li>`, so it doesnt know its not a paragraph, so its trying to help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [remove filter](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#remove) like this :

```
{{ host | markdownify | remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>' }}
```

Comment: This does indeed work perfectly. I actually came here looking for an *alternate* solution, because when I thought of this, it seemed a little bit barbaric.

Comment: Five years later ... I wonder is there also a filter that lets me clip off the first 3 and the last 4 letters, to avoid removing inner `p` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Well... It's quite old question, but still actual.

You can use `| remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>'` like [David Jacquel answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30828197/14831978) before. But it will remove every `<p>` tag in the text.

But if you want to remove `<p>`-tag wrapping only in cases there is only one `<p>` node, you'll need more complex solution.

There are few ways to do that without external plugins and filters.

And this is my solution:

```
{%- assign arr = yourTextVar | markdownify | strip | split: "<p>" -%}
{%- if arr.size > 2 -%}
  {{ arr | join: "<p>" | prepend: "<p>" }}
{%- else -%}
  {{ arr[1] | remove: "</p>" }}
{%- endif -%}
```

It'll split the text on empty `<p>` tag and will ignore anything like `<p id="my-id">`

Answer (score 1):

I failed with "killing" the `<p>` and `</p>`.

So I added a css-class to the p-element, e.g. `.handle-as-span`, then I was able to "manipulate" the p-element with css (change from block to inline).

```markdown
{: .handle-as-span }
![Image Alt Tag](path/to/image)
```

It should also work for lists / tables in markdown. I learned that the `{: .handle-as-span }` needs to be placed sometimes before the block, sometimes after. Just try it out. It is still ugly, but at least I was able to have my design not broken.

```css
p.handle-as-span {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use md.renderInline() to remove the `<p>` tag

Comment: This can be done on pure Liquid or should I need to mess with Jekyll code?